# Repopulating a Django form for the second time

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am making a basic blog platform with Django, I have added in an edit page where I can save a new and edited version, and have also added in a delete option. When the delete button is clicked, a new template is rendered asking for confirmation or cancellation of deletion. When I click 'yes' the post deletes itself as required, when I click 'no' it returns to the 'edit' page. The problem is that when it returns to the 'edit' page the form that is there is no longer populated, all the fields are empty. Is there any way I can configure the 'no' option to return to the 'edit' page with all the data filled in? Please advise if the question is unclear. Thank you.

**views.py**

```
def edit_post(request, slug):

    post=get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)
    form = BlogForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)

    context = {
        'title': post.title,
        'post': post,
        'form': form,
        }

    if 'save' in request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())

    elif 'delete' in request.POST:
        return render(request, 'Blog/confirm-deletion.html',delete_context)

    #Now delete template is shown, and view takes 'yes' or 'no' option

    elif 'yes' in request.POST:
        post.delete()
        messages.success(request, 'Post was successfully deleted')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_list'))

    elif 'no' in request.POST:
        form = BlogForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        context = {
            'title': post.title,
            'post': post,
            'form': form,
            }
        return render(request, 'Blog/edit_post.html', context)
        #PROBLEM HERE: CAN'T GET *NO* OPTION TO RETURN TO FILLED OUT FORM PAGE

return render(request, 'Blog/edit_post.html', context)
```

**confirm-deletion.html**

```
{% extends 'Blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method='POST' action = '' enctype='multipart/form-data'> {% csrf_token%}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete {{title}}?</p>
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'yes' value = 'Yes'/>
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'no' value = 'No'/>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

from django import forms
from .models import Blog

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = [
        'title',
        'category',
        'content',
        'draft'
        ]
```

Comment: When you click 'no', all the fields in that `<form>` tag will be submitted to the server. If you want the blog form fields to be submitted, then you need to put the form in the same tag.

Comment: @Alasdair so the information being resubmitted to the 'edit' page is coming from the 'yes/no' form rather than the blog form, and thats why the fields are being left blank?

Comment: @Alisdair, just tried it, works perfectly. If you want to leave your comment as an answer I'll select it as the most helpful.  Greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form, only the fields in that `<form>` tag will be submitted. For example, say you have two form tags on the page:

```
<form method='POST' action = '' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
    {% csrf_token%}
    {{ form }}
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>

<form method='POST' action = '' enctype='multipart/form-data'> {% csrf_token%}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete {{title}}?</p>
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'yes' value = 'Yes'/>
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'no' value = 'No'/>
</form>
```

When you click the 'no' button, the fields from the post form will not be submitted, because they are in a different form tag.

To submit the form data when you click 'no', you need to include the form in the same tag:

```
<form method='POST' action = '' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
    {% csrf_token%}
    {{ form }}
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete {{title}}?</p>
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'yes' value = 'Yes'/>
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'no' value = 'No'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your code, but why are you recreating the form in the `elif 'no'` clause? In fact, isn't that code repeating what's already been done, and can't you just do something like:

```
elif 'no' in request.POST:
    pass
```

Comment: Unfortunately if 'no' isn't clicked/selected, then the user will just remain on the 'confirm-deletion.html' page until either yes or no is selected. So if I use _pass_ on 'no', I won't have the option of going back to the original 'edit' page, unless I use my browser back button (which is sloppy on my part so I'd rather avoid that)

Comment: @MattCraig Why is that? Won't it execute the line "return render(request, 'Blog/edit_post.html', context)" ?

An alternative solution I see is to just clear request.POST and use that to call the edit_post function.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit 'delete' does a new alert window come up? If so instead of making the 'no' button a submit button you can have it just close the alert box. Maybe something like `window.close()` if it's opening a new HTML form.

Comment: For now I'm just rendering a new template/html page, so the server loads a fresh page when 'delete' is selected. That's a good idea though, I'll probably set that up later with JavaScript (unless there's a neat way to do it in Django/Python?)